# Long term availability of WS2812B or any Neo-pixel

Tags: led-strip, manufacturing, ws2812b, manufacturing-process

I am considering the use of Neo-pixel or WS2812B components in a project that we are planning to run for the next ten years with mass-scale production. I am curious about the feasibility of sourcing these components from suppliers such as China, Digikey, or other reputable manufacturers.
I want to use 3-5 RGB LEDs for my project, which I can control using single wire from ESP32.

I have compiled a list of potential models from Digikey, including options from well-known brands like Adafruit, Sparkfun, and Inolux. Any insights or advice regarding the availability and reliability of these components would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello and welcome.  How big is "mass scale" for your project?

Comment: The tap size of WS2812B is 4500 pcs/reel. Let's put it this way, even if you want to buy a few reel of WS2812B won't cause global shortage, and there are plenty of supply.

Comment: I would bet my pinky that you'll be able to buy WS2812B in ten years. Even if something better comes out tomorrow, and there have already been several improved variants that haven't displaced them yet, there's millions of units out there, guaranteeing a strong after-market and long-term low-run production for people in your situation. If there's a market, there will be a supply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ESP32 (Espressif Systems of Shanghai) and WS2812B (Worldsemi of Dongguan) are both Chinese companies. The former is fabless, not sure about the second. If you're buying the latter through a hobbyist brand such as Adafruit or Sparkfun they still come out of the one factory in the gritty light industrial town of Dongguan.

There is seldom, if ever, any real guarantee of long-term availability. The WS2812B are made for broad consumer applications, so there is better likelihood than if they were aimed at a narrow fickle high-volume sector such as mobile phones or even automobiles. Some companies such as Microchip have a reputation of not EOLing parts very quickly, but that doesn't mean they'll necessarily be available with reasonable lead times.

If you want some idea of the future you can extrapolate from the past- both devices have been available for some years and have been (afaik) in reliable supply even when big-name suppliers such as ST were quoting insanely long lead times.

There are various mitigation techniques- such as buying enough to cover redesign time (assuming something similar becomes available). There may also be similar parts available from other Chinese suppliers such as Xinglight. A reel (盘) seems to be around $150 USD FOB, so not expensive. Of course if irrational geopolitical factors enter into it, then all bets are off, you might think about retiring the product and perhaps yourself.